# Dataflow read GCS error

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Does the following exception look familiar to anyone? The exactly same pipeline and data worked last week but got failed couple of times for the same exception today. I didn't see any footprint of my code from the stack trace. Wondering what it might be related to...  for example, GCS read quota?

And, since it went fine on my direct runner, for these type of Dataflow exceptions, how can I debug on Dataflow?

```
{


insertId:  "7289985381136617647:828219:0:906922"  
 jsonPayload: {
  exception:  "java.io.IOException: Failed to advance reader of source: gs://fiona_dataflow/tmp/BigQueryExtractTemp/5c813875537d4c1a89b74a800bb37c50/000000000864.avro range [0, 808559590)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$BoundedReaderIterator.advance(WorkerCustomSources.java:605)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation$SynchronizedReaderIterator.advance(ReadOperation.java:398)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:193)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:158)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:75)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.executeWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:383)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:355)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:286)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:134)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:114)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:101)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.geotab.bigdata.streaming.mapserver.backfill.MapServerBatchBeamApplication.lambda$main$fd9fc9ef$1(MapServerBatchBeamApplication.java:82)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySourceBase$1.apply(BigQuerySourceBase.java:211)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySourceBase$1.apply(BigQuerySourceBase.java:205)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.AvroSource$AvroBlock.readNextRecord(AvroSource.java:579)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.BlockBasedSource$BlockBasedReader.readNextRecord(BlockBasedSource.java:223)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource$FileBasedReader.advanceImpl(FileBasedSource.java:473)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.OffsetBasedSource$OffsetBasedReader.advance(OffsetBasedSource.java:267)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$BoundedReaderIterator.advance(WorkerCustomSources.java:602)
    ... 14 more
"   
  job:  "2018-04-23_07_30_32-17662367668739576363"   
  logger:  "com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WorkItemStatusClient"   
  message:  "Uncaught exception occurred during work unit execution. This will be retried."   
  stage:  "s19"   
  thread:  "27"   
  work:  "1213589185295287945"   
  worker:  "mapserverbatchbeamapplica-04230730-s20x-harness-713d"
```

Comment: I've seen this error before being attributed to the job running in a different region than that of the bucket it reads from. If, for example, you've uploaded your data in EU and attempted to access them from US soon afterward, limitations in bandwidth might result in your reads being network throttled. Basically you should wait for sometime (even days) before accessing data from US after uploading them in EU. Does this fit your case?

Comment: @LefterisS not really, the data and clusters are all in the same region. but thanks to your reply. it now sounds more like a intrinsic and temporary Dataflow service issue to me. Since it doesn't show up in my recent few runs